# ImageMagick-6, how to adjust brightness of background only of scanned page, without touching the text

Tags: brightness, gimp, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a pictures of scanned book, jpeg format. All pages have gray backround with some noise, due to grayscale mode used when scan. ImageMagick-6

```
Image info:
Resolution: 200x200
Colorspace: Gray
Type: Grayscale
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth: gray: 8-bit
Gamma: 0.454545
Background color: gray(255)
Border color: gray(223)
Matte color: gray(189)
Transparent color: gray(0)
Interlace: None
```

Does it possible to adjust (increase) brightness of background only, without touching the brightness of text itself?
I tried use command `convert -brightness-contrast 10x0 page1.jpg out-001.jpg` - but
this increases the brightness of both background and text. I want to change the brightness of the background only(remove gray background) - without touching the text itself. Is that possible? If that's not possible, is there method to do same in GIMP?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK:

`convert 'INPUT_FILE' -fuzz '20%' -opaque 'YOUR_GREY_COLOUR' -opaque 'YOUR_TARGET_COLOR' 'TARGRT_FILE'`

can make this. The trick od that replace input color with -fuzz tolerance to desired target color. I think this is close what you want.

Comment: It's not clear how to define the existing gray color value, because the color isn't the same everywhere (like noise), I used Gpick to check gray color, the gray shades varies #F0F0F0, #EDEDED, #F1F1F1.. Page [sample](https://postimg.cc/fVZMS9J3)

Comment: You don't have exact grey value - you have load image, probe sample value in Krita or Gimp and play with -fuzz option. Believe me: results are suprisingly good and maybe acceptable. The only catch are images - convert can broke them with greater -fuzz precentage.